# Library/service/API that can be used to assign relevant tags to content

Tags: nlp, classification

For example, let's say we feed in this content:

```
{
    "title" : "Bitcoin drops 20% after $70M worth of bitcoin was stolen from Bitfinex exchange"
    "body" : "Bitfinex, one of the most popular cryptocurrency exchanges online, has suffered a major hack. The company has posted a note on its website detailing the security breach, and while it doesn’t mention a total amount, one of their employees confirmed on Reddit that the total amount stolen was 119,756 bitcoins."
}
```

Note, this format is arbitary. The service/API/library will take this data, scan it and assign topic tags such as **Bitcoin**, **Crypto Currency**, **Blockchain**, & **Bitfinex**.

Is there such a thing available to people who can't really build their own?

Comment: *This format is arbitrary*. I assume that it will be JSON, just not a fixed structure?

Comment: **What is the subject area?** You cannot expect any API to cover all the worlds topics. It would have to return every noun and name.

Comment: What I meant was that the format can be anything. I am not picky about that. And subject area... well I guess the broader the better cause I want this system to tag articles from a broad range of topics.

Comment: What would the library need to be created in/compatible with?

Comment: Should compatibility really be an issue here? I mean I could feed the service data in any format it wants, and I could convert the returned data to my personal format as well. And its going to be JSON anyway most likely, if such a service exists that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Open Calais](http://www.opencalais.com/opencalais-demo/). Here is the result I get from your proposed body:

Topics:
Technology Internet 84%
Labor 82%
Business Finance 65%

Social Tags:
Bitcoin
Cryptocurrency
Reddit

[I'm searching for something really similar](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35383/tool-that-automatically-organize-short-descriptions-by-topic?noredirect=1#comment51114_35383) to you but I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like the only viable option.